# Porque no muestra la alerta esperada?

Tags: javascript

```js
(() => {
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentloaded", () => 
    tc = document.getElementById("coor");
    tc.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
      alert(evt.clientX);
    });
  });
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="button" id="coor" value="Coordenadas" />
</body>

</html>
```

No me muestra ni alerta, ni error, lo que quiero lograr es mostrar las coordenadas X, al cliquear el botón.

Comment: ¿Alguien podría indicar __cuál es el error de sintaxis__? Gracias.

Comment: No se incluye información de lo buscado/investigado. Falta una descripción de lo que se espera que haga el código.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes el nombre del evento mal escrito. Es `DOMContentLoaded` no `DOMContentloaded`:

```js
(()=> {      
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",()=>{
      tc = document.getElementById("coor");
      tc.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
         alert(evt.clientX);
      });
   });
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="coor" value="Coordenadas"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Si es un error tipográfico la pregunta debería ser cerrada